# How to play both mp4 and hls videos in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming, html5-video

This is a general question i need your expert opinion.

I am a new bee in Reactjs and i have a requirement like ,i want to play both HLS and mp4 videos using reactjs. I have a live streaming and recorded url to play.

I found lot of options to do it. I want a single player which is to be created as a component and able to play hls(.m3u8 format) and mp4 videos.

Could you please suggest me a better way or some sample tutorials?

Comment: react is still javascript commonly used with html5, i see no problem to create video component which will support playlists. Also I bet there are a lot of such components made already.

Comment: Shameless promotion of my npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jplayer

Both formats are supported although it doesn't support playlists yet. Demo http://react-jplayer.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: I am using `videojs` plus the hls plugin, wrapped in a react component. Works with both mp4 and hls playlists, adapive streaming, etc. Edit: and it works on ios safari, and it can be played inline with `playsInline` prop on the `video` element, which is kinda hard to achieve with free players.

Answer (score 1):

[VideoJS](http://videojs.com) is a full features HLS player that works pretty well, and

1. Works in iOS Safari
2. Support `playsInline` prop to avoid fullscreen on iOS mobil devices

*Note: you can also use autoplay on iOS, as long as the video starts muted*

First, you need to add dependencies to videojs and HLS plugin in you main HTML, like explained [in the docs of videojs HLS plugin](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/blob/master/README.md)

Then, you can use a react wrapper like below, modify to your own taste:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class VideoPlayer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        style: PropTypes.object,
        onVideoEvent: PropTypes.func,
        src: PropTypes.string,
        poster: PropTypes.string
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        style: {},
        onVideoEvent: console.log,
        src: '',
        poster: ''
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        // This is a hack because I don't import video.js as a hard dependency
        // but load it alongside my app bundle
        if (typeof videojs === 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(this.componentDidMount, 500);
            return;
        }
        const { onVideoEvent } = this.props;
        this.player = videojs(this.videoNode);
        const exportEvents = ['timeupdate', 'play', 'playing', 'pause',
            'ended', 'error', 'waiting']; 
        exportEvents.forEach(ev => this.player.on(ev, this.props.onVideoEvent));
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        this.player && this.player.dispose();
        this.player = null;
    }

    render = () => (
        <div alt="snap"
            key="media"
            style={ this.props.style }
            data-vjs-player>

            <video playsInline
                className="video-js"
                preload="auto"
                poster={ this.props.poster }
                ref={ r => { this.videoNode = r; } } >

                <source src={ this.props.src } type="application/x-mpegURL" />

            </video>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Full options and documentation of Video.js with all customization and capabilities of the player [can be found here](http://docs.videojs.com/)